# What is the primary purpose of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Why do you visit Stack Overflow? Why do you think people visit Stack Overflow? What is this website about?

Answer (score 13):

The "About" page sums it up nicely:

> Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that's free.

Comment: and I truely hate the expertsexchange website.

Comment: Talk about a poorly-named website. Some things suffer greatly from not being allowed to have spaces in their URLs...

Comment: You've left open the answer to the OP's question. What the site is can be differentiated from its primary purpose.

Answer (score 6):

To make me smrt!

But I digress. The purpose of this site is stated in the [About section.](https://stackoverflow.com/about)

> Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that's free. Free to ask questions, free to answer questions, free to read, free to index, built with plain old HTML, no fake rot13 text on the home page, no scammy google-cloaking tactics, no salespeople, no JavaScript windows dropping down in front of the answer asking for $12.95 to go away. You can register if you want to collect karma and win valuable flair that will appear next to your name, but otherwise, it's just free. And fast. Very, very fast.

And what type of questions is in the [FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: There are ads! Those career ads with the dying starfish!

Answer (score 1):

I like to see the POV of people who are **experienced** in the subjects presented here.

Sometimes, when you search google for something programming related, you don't even know how to start, don't even know the needed keywords to search for your problem/question. But in SO people can understand you because they **lived** what you're asking. You can have practical advice in lot of ways - and vice versa. Questions and answer here inspire **trust** most of the time.

Adding this subjective factor with an objective one - the plataform is simple, non-intrusive and fast - is just a killer.

Personally, another motivation I found in using SO is to improve my english since it isn't my first language, and since I'm a developer, I would benefit myself twice.

Answer (score -6):

Stackoverflow is a website where software developers can gain reputation in the form of reputation points and badges by asking questions and giving answers.

Comment: -1 this is not the purpose of stackoverflow. The purpose is to provide a format in which we can get our questions answered.

Comment: Well, that was probably the original intention, but the way it works I doubt many users care about much besides their points and badges –

Comment: @unknown: I would argue, vehemently, otherwise. Especially once you hit a certain point with your rep, where it really doesn't matter much anymore. All the flair is nice, and rewarding, but the reality is I think most of us go there specifically to help and be helped. That's why I go. (Well, that, and I've now taken it upon myself to try and clean up the site with edits ... But that's because I care deeply about the success of of the site.)

Comment: Is the purpose of football to play an energetic outdoors game, or to get the ball across the opposing goal line?

Comment: I can't imagine that Skeet jumps around and does jumping jacks every time he gets a "Nice Answer" badge at this point.

Comment: Hey, be gentle -- the question is a discussion, if this is the reason this guy visits SO, you shouldn't down-vote him for answering the question.